# Android studio Error in Build apk

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to install and run this application in my phone, but it gives an error. Please help me.

**Error Message:**

```
Target device: huawei-huawei_rio_l01
    Target device: huawei-huawei_rio_l01
Installing APK: H:\aaaaAndroidWorkShop\Project\LavinPanel\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    Installing APK: H:\aaaaAndroidWorkShop\Project\LavinPanel\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/Site40200.LavinPanel
    Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/Site40200.LavinPanel
Installing Site40200.LavinPanel
    Installing Site40200.LavinPanel
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/Site40200.LavinPanel"
    DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/Site40200.LavinPanel"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Site40200.LavinPanel
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/Site40200.LavinPanel
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]
    Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]
```

**Error Screenshots:**

[image: screenshot_1]

[image: screenshot_2]

Answer (score 0):

check your manifest file
Replace this sort of data with :

```
<service
android:name="com.example.sam.AppService"
android:process="screen" >
</service>
```

like this

```
<service
android:name="com.example.sam.AppService"
android:process=":screen" >
</service>
```

i think it will work